# Rails Passenger and Nginx + GeoIP module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I install as always passanger gem and then:

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

and I chose auto configuration and

```
/opt/nginx
```

folder for nginx.

Now when I wrote

```
nginx -V
```

I only see

```
nginx:command not found
```

usr/local/bin is empty.

Of course app works but I try to install GeoIP and just can't check what modules nginx have installed.

ANSWER:

Standard auto installation of rvmsudo passenger-nginx-module doesn't load aditional modules.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something went wrong with the installation process. According to the [passenger official docs](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/digital_ocean/nginx/oss/trusty/install_passenger.html), to install passenger do this (considering your are using Ubuntu 14.04):

```
# Install our PGP key and add HTTPS support for APT
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates

# Add our APT repository
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'
sudo apt-get update

# Install Passenger + Nginx
sudo apt-get install -y nginx-extras passenger
```

If you already have nginx on the system this command will just upgrade Nginx to Phusion's version (with Passenger compiled in).

start it:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

check if its working by running

```
sudo passenger-config validate-install
```

Comment: right now passenger-config command not found ... hm I need to make some test on other server and they check your solution

Comment: I strongly recommend following [this official tutorial](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/), you can't go wrong with it. Whenever I need to deploy a new server I aways refer to it. Good luck :)

Comment: passenger status ok: Instance: 36z5xOmg (nginx/1.8.1 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.24) ... there where no errors on installation ... must be some other solution

Comment: ok because I install it by rvm I need to use rvmsudo pasenger-config .... and its also ok, no errors... problem is that I install it in /opt folder and not /etc ... I think ....